# Inserting Separate Optimization Problems Adjacently

Tags: columns

I am facing an issue on how to include two separate optimization problems in two columns in LaTeX. I am using TeXMaker. I want to include the optimization problems depicted in the picture. I can't pinpoint anything relevant about optimization problems, but only for equations.[image: Optimization in Two Columns]

I know how to write each one separately, but I don't know how to combine them in the way depicted in the picture. I am using optidef environment.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is the problem I want to put one next to each other:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[long]{optidef}

\newcommand{\vecx}{\mbox{\boldmath $x$}}
\newcommand{\vecu}{\mbox{\boldmath $u$}}
\newcommand{\vecU}{\mbox{\boldmath $U$}}

\begin{document}

\def\mathbi#1{\textbf{\em #1}}

\begin{maxi}
 {}{\mathbi{a}_i^T\vecx}{}{}
 \addConstraint{\mathbi{D}_i\mathbi{a}_i}{\leq \mathbi{d}_i,}
\end{maxi}

 \begin{mini}
  {}{\mathbi{p}_i^T\mathbi{d}_i}{}{}
   \addConstraint{\mathbi{p}_i^T\mathbi{D}_i}{= \vecx}
  \addConstraint{\mathbi{p}_i}{\geq 0}
 \end{mini}

 \end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Welcome! Could you post a full compilable code of what you tried?

Comment: @Bernard here is the code I am trying to put one next to other:

Comment: Did you try with two minipages separated by a left-rightarrow?